# Matching Air blower CFM vs HEPA filter CFM, and ΔP in WG, for laminar flow design

Tags: design, pressure, airflow

I am trying to build a laminar flow box using instructions at these YouTube links for [design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDaJW77Wb5Q) and [build](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj4qk6I-hy8).

They recommended getting a Dayton squirrel cage air blower model [1TDU2](https://electricmotorwarehouse.com/dayton-model-1tdu2-blower-1202-cfm-1390-rpm-115-230v-60-50hz-4c831/) rated at 1202 CFM. The performance sheet for this air blower ( CFM vs. in wg) can be seen at this [link](http://www.electricmotorwarehouse.com/content/Dayton/blower_specs/ITDU2.pdf) I've already purchased this... (can be returned)

I am now considering buying one of these HEPA filters from Ebay:

**A.** CAMFIL FARR. 855023669, PX-21.75-44.00-9-40-FU-00-00-0 MEGALAM PANEL HEPA FILTER ([link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/CAMFIL-FARR-855023669-PX-21-75-44-00-9-40-FU-00-00-0-MEGALAM-PANEL-HEPA-FILTER/361127918011?hash=item5414e6b9bb%3Ag%3Ax3YAAOSwOuBbvjIb%3Asc%3AFedExHomeDelivery%2123455%21US%21-1&LH_ItemCondition=3)) = 0.40 in W.G. / 100FPM / 554CFM

**B.** CAMFIL FARR 85502A548 MEGALAM PANEL P7-23.12-47.12-5-08-00-7D-00-0
([link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/CAMFIL-FARR-85502A548-MEGALAM-PANEL-P7-23-12-47-12-5-08-00-7D-00-0/281516905913?hash=item418bb715b9%3Ag%3AxIoAAOSwuMFUfMWQ%3Asc%3AFedExHomeDelivery%2123455%21US%21-1&LH_ItemCondition=3)) = 0.58 in W.G. / 100FPM / 704CFM

**C.** CAMFIL FARR 855024774 MEGALAM PANEL P7-18.00-48.00-2-03-SR-00-00-0 PACK OF 2
([link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/CAMFIL-FARR-855024774-MEGALAM-PANEL-P7-18-00-48-00-2-03-SR-00-00-0-PACK-OF-2/281516930978?hash=item418bb777a2%3Ag%3AzKcAAOSwkNZUfMmT%3Asc%3AFedExHomeDelivery%2123455%21US%21-1&LH_ItemCondition=3&autorefresh=true)) = 0.71 in W.G. / 105FPM / 550CFM

My requirement for maintaining microbial sterility are

**(i)** minimum 90 FPM

**(ii)** minimum 99.99% air purity

The help I seek is in the form of your answers to my questions below, please:

I know there is a large mismatch between air blower CFM rating and any of these filters recommended CFM rating.

**1.** Are any of the filters listed above matched with my air blower in terms of CFM rating? I guess not, but I want to be sure.

**2.** Is matching of the air blower CFM and filter CFM done at zero pressure, or operating pressure drop water gauge (which varies across these 3 filters) ?

**3.** FYI, I will be using a pre-filter to get rid of large particulate matter, that contributes additionally 0.3 in WG pressure drop

**4.** If at total WG pressure drop, the air blower CFM is X, and the rated air filter CFM is Y, then for maintaining filter integrity, I know X < Y and X = Y is OK (where X > 90FPM). But how high can X get when X > Y ? 20% , 30% , 100% - something else?

**5.** What are the consequences of X >> Y ? Will it blow out the HEPA filter? And more air means exceeding capacity to capture particles, so more air, but partially dirty air, right?

**6.** Can anyone help me with who to read and interpret a Camfil Farr HEPA filter's label, especially the description e.g. PX-21.75-44.00-9-40-FU-00-00-0, P7-23.12-47.12-5-08-00-7D-00-0, P7-18.00-48.00-2-03-SR-00-00-0 etc.?

**7.** I was told that for my application, a "high flow" (~1000 CFM) thicker HEPA filter (11 5/8 in) is better than a "standard" thinner one (5 7/8 in) with only ~ 500 CFM. Is this a valid piece of advice, given my goals?

**8.** From Ebay or elsewhere, do forum users have friendly advice for a (an equally or more) cost effective alternative to these Camfil Farr HEPA filters?

Thanks, in advance. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/2390/10902

Comment: No it's not.... please read both contents carefully in this case, and responsibly post any comments that may reduce or eliminate the possibility of a response. This is not cross-posted, nor is it redundant or duplicated. I request you to change or delete your comment...And I will too. Thanks!

Comment: "possible".... and the Q I link to has the expression to calculate the pressure drop AND to approximate the fan curve...

Comment: I already have the fan curve from the manufacturer website. And know the delta pressure curve for the HEPA filter from Camfil Farr's tech people. My questions are different. I did notice use of "possible" but you continue to ignore the context of my questions, and the much wider range and number of questions asked. So I will no longer dignify your comments with a response.